# assigning a value to form widget

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

i have a form widget in _form.php

```
echo $form['catcher_id']->renderLabel();  //the label
echo $form['catcher_id']->renderError();  //the validator
```

symfony created the base class:

```
<?php
/**
 * LpmService form base class.
 */
abstract class BaseLpmServiceForm extends BaseFormPropel
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->setWidgets(array(
      'id'                   => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
      'name'                 => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'wap_home'             => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'call_center_number'   => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
     [color=#FF4000] 'catcher_id'           => new sfWidgetFormPropelChoice(array('model' => 'LpmCatcher', 'add_empty' => false)),[/color]
      'price_description'    => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'logo'                 => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'invalid_msisdn_text'  => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'terms_and_conditions' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'service_code'         => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
    ));

    $this->setValidators(array(
      'id'                   => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array($this->getObject()->getId()), 'empty_value' => $this->getObject()->getId(), 'required' => false)),
      'name'                 => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 64, 'required' => false)),
      'wap_home'             => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 256, 'required' => false)),
      'call_center_number'   => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 13, 'required' => false)),
      'catcher_id'           => new sfValidatorPropelChoice(array('model' => 'LpmCatcher', 'column' => 'id')),
      'price_description'    => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 128, 'required' => false)),
      'logo'                 => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 255, 'required' => false)),
      'invalid_msisdn_text'  => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 255, 'required' => false)),
      'terms_and_conditions' => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 750, 'required' => false)),
      'service_code'         => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 3, 'required' => false)),
    ));
    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('lpm_service[%s]');
    $this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);
    parent::setup();
  }
  public function getModelName()
  {
    return 'LpmService';
  }
}
```

and i re-created the dropdown list manually so i can incorporate a "onchange" event:

```
<select name="services" onchange="refreshPage(this.form.services)" id="droplist">
           <?php
              $catcher_names = LpmCatcherPeer::getByAllNames();
              foreach($catcher_names as $row)
              {
                  ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row->getName()."/".$row->getId(); ?>" <?php 
                      if($row->getName() == $catcher_name) echo 'selected="selected"'?>><?php echo $row->getName();?></option>
                    <?php
              }
                  ?>
            </select>
```

how can i assign a value to `echo $form['catcher_id']` because now when i select a value from the dropdown and click submit the validator says that catcher_id is required(because i created dropdown manually), so how can i set the value manually???

i have:

```
$form['catcher_id']->getWidget()->setAttribute('value', '11');
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work in your template:

```
<?php $form->setDefault('catcher_id', 123) ?>
```

... or in your action:

```
$this->form->setDefault('catcher_id', 123);
```

Comment: nope im afraid i still get the validator saying catcher_id is required

Answer (score 1):

Instead of recoding the select, I would use the select's ID and bind the event in Javascript:

```
function init()
{
  var el_to_bind = document.getElementById( 'lpm_service_catcher_id' );
  el_to_bind.onchange = my_onchange_handler;
}

function my_onchange_handler( el )
{
  // do your stuff here
}
```

Or, with jQuery,

```
$('#lpm_service_catcher_id').change( function() {
  // do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your manually created select's name match the one that would've been generated by symfony.

Assuming lpm_service is the value returned by your form's `getName()` call, and that you use the default name format, the name of the select needs to be `lpm_service[catcher_id]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're assigning distinct values to the select as the validator does. You are using:

```
<select>
<option value='name/id' ...>
</select>
```

And the validator searchs only for id

```
$this->setValidators(array(
...
      'catcher_id' => new sfValidatorPropelChoice(
                      array('model' => 'LpmCatcher', 'column' => 'id')),
...
    ));
```

Thats why the validator is failing and it doesn't sets you the default value.

So what I would really do is use the default render, set the value with

```
$this->form->setDefault('catcher_id', 123);
```

like **Tom** said and attach the onchangehandler like **yitznewton** said.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do that manually. You can set any attribute you want on a widget. You should do this in `LpmServiceForm`

```
$this->getWidget('catcher_id')->setAttribute('onchange', 'refreshPage(this.form.services)');
```

and render the form as usual.